# Cordova plugin does not work after a private member variable to the class

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on a Cordova app on Android, I had a plugin before and everything works just fine, after I added a private member variable to the plugin class, it stopped working, and it works after I removed the new variable. 
what is the problem?

I found the problem:

private SimpleDateFormat dtFmtr = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy hh:mm A");

The "A" in the format string should be "a", but I did not get any error or warning in the debug windows!

Thanks
John

Comment: Can't tell much without any code...

Comment: You are using Angular Framework ? Ionic ? Tell more please, share code and more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

private SimpleDateFormat dtFmtr = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy hh:mm A");

The "A" in the format string should be "a", but I did not get any error or warning in the debug windows!